# How to get a stable 3.3V/2A output out of a single cell (18650 Li-ion) battery?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator, buck-boost, 18650

In my tiny quadcopter, I need to power a long range wifi card which take 3.3V/2A max as input. The quad runs off a single high current 18650 Li-ion battery.

Are there any chips or modules that will produce this kind of output?

The reason is that the battery voltage will be ranging from 2.7V to 4.2V depending on the charge, so I can't see the use of a buck or boost converter here.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I can't see the use of a buck or boost converter here."* A combined (step-up/step-down) buck/boost converter is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: My solution would be a boost converter to take it to 5V, then a buck converter to bring that down to 3V3. There are inefficiencies in this, but most buck-boosts I've seen aren't very efficient anyway, and a 5V boost, 3V3 buck are both simple devices you can look at in isolation.

Comment: A battery IS a 'stable' source.   The nominal '3.3V' power requirement does not signify unless we also know the allowable range, and the '2A' requirement is presumably a maximum?   The need for something more elaborate than a wire is not clear.

Comment: Aren’t there already regulators in your quad providing 3.3V, or possibly some other stable voltage? Also what are the specs for your “high current” battery, and how much does the rest of the drone use?

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at something like the [TPS63805](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63806.pdf?ts=1704398866072&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fnon-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators%252Fbuck-boost-inverting%252Fproducts.html) non-inverting buck-boost from TI.

It's fairly simple to use:

[image]

It produces 3.3 V out over your entire input range, and the efficiency is pretty high:

[image]

I don't think you'd do better in a similar solution size and cost cascading a boost with a buck.  You can likely find similar parts from ADI, MPS or others as well.